# Most efficient way to remove separately-stored offsets to measurement reading data to get "raw" data

Tags: postgresql

I'm not sure how to define this question so couldn't figure out what to search for to see if this has already been asked, so apologies.

I have a table containing measurement calibration offsets for sensors:

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_history
(
  site_id              VARCHAR(8)      NOT NULL,
  sensor_id            SMALLINT        NOT NULL,
  calibration_degrees  NUMERIC(5, 2)   NOT NULL,
  updated_dtm          TIMESTAMPTZ     NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT pk_sensor_history
    PRIMARY KEY (site_id, sensor_id, updated_dtm)
);

-- Example data:
-- '123', 1, -10.0, '2021-09-30 09:00:10.000 + 0100'
-- '123', 1, -20.0, '2021-09-30 09:00:30.000 + 0100'
```

This table has a row added if a sensor's calibration offset is updated.

There's a much bigger table containing the sensor measurements themselves, where a reading is taken numerous times a minute:

```
CREATE TABLE reading
(
  site_id                 VARCHAR(8)      NOT NULL,
  sensor_id               SMALLINT        NOT NULL,
  reading_dtm             TIMESTAMPTZ(0)  NOT NULL,
  value                   NUMERIC(5,2)    NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT pk_reading
    PRIMARY KEY (site_id, sensor_id, reading_dtm)
);

-- Example data:
-- (steady measurement rise masked by applied offset values)
-- '123', 1, '2021-09-30 09:00:03.000 + 0100', 60
-- '123', 1, '2021-09-30 09:00:13.000 + 0100', 52
-- '123', 1, '2021-09-30 09:00:23.000 + 0100', 54
-- '123', 1, '2021-09-30 09:00:33.000 + 0100', 46
```

Unfortunately the calibration offset is applied to the reading prior to the measurement being stored.

I'm trying to find the most efficient way of coming up with the "raw" measurements over a chosen timeframe, i.e. check if an offset was applied when measurements were stored and then remove the offset.